# Could not start network bridge due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to define a network bridge between a broker in a non-primary site and a broker in a primary site with the expected behavior that messages produced in a non-primary-site get forwarded to the primary site and processed there.

After doing some research online I added a `<networkConnectors/>` element to the xml file for my non-primary broker pointing to the primary broker.

This is the XML file for the primary broker:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="Broker" dataDirectory="SOME_PATH" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true" advisorySupport="false" schedulerSupport="true">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="20mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="20mb">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy> 

        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="SOME_PATH"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="50 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="primary_broker" uri="tcp://localhost:2384"/>
        </transportConnectors>

    </broker>    
</beans>
```

This is the XML file for the non-primary broker:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="Broker" dataDirectory="SOME_PATH" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true" advisorySupport="false" schedulerSupport="true">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="20mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="20mb">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy> 

        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector name="bridge" uri="static:(tcp://PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME:2384)"/>
        </networkConnectors>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="SOME_PATH"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="50 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="secondary_broker" uri="tcp://localhost:2386"/>
        </transportConnectors>

    </broker>    
</beans>
```

The error I am seeing when I am trying to start up the non-primary broker is:

```
Could not start network bridge between: vm://Broker?async=false&network=true and: tcp://PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME:2384 due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I did some investigation and got the IT team involved and confirmed that it is not a firewall issue.

I tried to set up a network between 2 brokers on the same non-primary host. I used the same configuration (i.e. just by updating the `uri` value in  `networkConnector`) and this time the network was established successfully.

I am not sure what is going on and why using the same configuration, and assuming there's no network issue, I am able to bridge 2 brokers on the same host, but not on different hosts.

I am using ActiveMQ v5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `<transportConnector/>` element in the primary broker was configured with `localhost`
After changing it to use the actual server name instead it worked

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="primary_broker" uri="tcp://SERVER_NAME:2384"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using activemq version 5.13.3 (or higher), you only need to create a shared file system mount point, and specify it's location in the activemq.xml config file:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
   <levelDB directory="/shared-File-System-Mount-Point"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

I've been using AWS efs file system and it works perfectly.
these is no need to specify a network connecter.
when loading, one of the activemq servers will lock a file at this location, and will become the master.
if it should fail for any reason, one of the available slaves will become the master automatically.

more info can be found [here](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html)

also, [this](http://kevinboone.net/README_amqutil.html) is an awesome tool to [test the fail over](http://kevinboone.net/amqmasterslave.html).